# Globalization and resources files needed to "fall back" when missing item

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, globalization

I'm using Globalization and resources files in a 4.5 C# asp.net web forms app. 
It all works very well. But I was wondering if there is a better way to manage items when one is missing.
I.e. I use a custom set of language files and every once and a while one is not translated.
so when the user gets to an area inside the app with that label (for instance) it is blank.

How can I default back to my English res file if the language of choice is missing that item?

Code:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(sLanguageSelection);
 lblSomeTextBox.Text = Resources.myapp._255.ToString();
```

Label 255 in English file is populated, in other languages is blank. I would like to "fall back" to English when blank.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what? Those weren't tags. It defined the technology that is being used, ie ASP.NET framework 4.5. I added those after I discovered a very similar post but their question was with ruby. Are we not defining tech used in posts? I guess those are to be tags only? I swear I've seen tech in the titles. Ok, if that's the requirement.

Comment: Adding tags became an issue since the website has so many JS errors that keep popping up in my debugger, messing tags up. :) love this website by the way.

Comment: Tech is ok in the title, but only as an integral part of the title. Ask yourself how you would say this to a colleague, "I have a problem with C# ASP.NET 4.5 Globalization and resources files needed to fall back when missing item". I bet you'd ask without specifying the technology in the question.

Comment: not to a colleague, but to the world, yes. The generic statement about resources and globalization might mean many different tech's and many different implmentations. When I searched, ruby came up. This isn't ruby. So if I was going to answer this post I'd want to know C# and 4.5 :)

Comment: no one is responding due to the vagness of the topic title, minus tech.

Comment: No, the technology is in the tags, which is where we look for it on this site.